# java.util.Date equals() and getTime()

Tags: java

What  is the difference between these two :

```
java.util.Date obj1;
java.util.Date obj2;

obj1.equals(obj2)
obj1.getTime() == (obj2.getTime())
```

Has it got any millisecond difference?

Comment: `Date#getTime` returns a `long` and therefore does not have a `equals` method...

Comment: @MadProgrammer yes sorry  fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the implementation of [`Date#equals`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Date.java):

```
947     public boolean equals(Object obj) {
948         return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
949     }
```

it compares using `getTime` method.

[`Date#getTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) returns the "number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT", you cannot use `equals` on it since it's a `long`, see its signature:

```
public long getTime()
```

So you should simply:

```
obj1.equals(obj2)
```

or using `==` operator to compare the value returned from `getTime`.

Comment: *"Comparison of Date objects compares the objects themselves, not the content"* - Wrong - `return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();`

Comment: You're assuming that if you call `equals` on a `Date` object, you get the `equals` implementation from `Date`. But you might get the implementation from a subclass which has a different way of determining equality other than just checking the `getTime()` field.

Comment: OP are using `Date` in their example.

Comment: @MarounMaroun No, they have two variables of type `Date`. They don't specify that they were instantiated as `new Date`. If you have two `Date` variables as function parameters, someone can call that function with two `Timestamp`s.

Comment: @khelwood you're right, I assumed that OP are asking for `Date` object, not a subclass of it.

Answer (score 0):

the first one compares to `Dates`. the second one does not compile, because `long` (is returned by `getTime()`) is a primitive type and you can not call a `method` on a primitive type.

Comment: But, if in the spirit of things, you were to say `obj1.getTime() == obj2.getTime()` instead, then there is no difference between the two statements

Answer (score 0):

The `equals` method defined in [`Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) just checks if the `getTime()` returns the same for both object. So there really *shouldn't* be any different between using `equals` and checking the `getTime()` values yourself. If the libraries were all sensibly written, there wouldn't be.

However, at least one subclass of `Date` ([`java.sql.Timestamp`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html)) overrides `equals` and changes its meaning to be inconsistent with its baseclass. So if one of your `Date` objects happened to be a `Timestamp`, then its `equals` method **could produce a different result**.

Answer (score 0):

`obj1.getTime().equals(obj2.getTime()) can't compile, as`Date#getTime`returns a primitive`long` which does not have any methods.

If, other the other hand, you were to say `obj1.getTime() == obj2.getTime()`, then neither statement would be any different as the `Date#equals` method uses...

```
return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Second one will cause a compiler error. :)

`java.util.Date.getTime()` returns the primitive `long` and not the object type `Long`. You cannot invoke methods on a primitive type.
You are looking for, `Long.compare(obj1.getTime(),obj2.getTime())` which will return 0 if both are equal. Alternatively, `Long.valueOf(obj1.getTime()).equals(Long.valueOf(obj2.getTime())` can also be used. Both these convert `long` to `Long` before invoking the methods.

Secondly, in this particular case, both approaches will not result in different results. '.equals()' is meant to check if two objects are meaningfully equal to each other. As opposed to `java.util.Date` which is represented by a single `long` number, certain classes may have their equality defined by values of more than one property. For example, in a House class, equality will be defined by the aggregate of street address, city, zip code and country. In such a case, `.equals()` will be the only approach for equality.

Comment: The OP has updated the question, so your first statement is wrong. You last statement is also wrong - `return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();` - From the `Date#equals` method ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, what's wrong with the second statement? .equals is supposed to check for meaningful equality. In case of Date class, meaningful equality is defined as having the same long value representing them. When I say long representation is equal, I suppose it is implied that the classes must be of same type.

Comment: It sounds more like you are talking about the fact the `equals` is check to see if one object is equal to another (==) not that it's contents matches

Comment: Added a clarification.

Answer (score 0):

```
Date date1 = new Date();
Date date2 = new Date();
```

Case1: `date2.getTime == date1.getTime` This particular comparison, compares the number of milliseconds passes since 1970 till the instance of your both date objects. Data type will be primitive `long`.

Case2: `date2.equals(date1)` This particular comparison does the following,

`public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return obj instanceof Date && getTime() == ((Date) obj).getTime();
    }`

i.e case2 also compares the number of milliseconds passed since 1970 with an additional check of whether the comparable date is an instance of `Date` object.